# WorldServer or DataBase Broken Update?

Tags: azerothcore

Since an update I made this saturday, here are all the errors I get when launching the worldserver (take care, it's very long!) :

```
>>>> https://pastebin.com/0vQYjMJr
```

Is there a way to rollback to the last update I made a week ago? Note that I got all the SQL DB install files and SQL updates downloaded via a regular 'git pull' I made each week, but no DB Backup Export.
So, today I need to rollback to the last compile I made and be sure that the SQL updates will stop to the the last date of my compile, not the last of this saturday. I will try some, and get back here

Hope you will reply quickly

V.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found this : https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/issues/9763
It's just a bug. In fact, the server is still running correctly. Maybe an update will fix it soon.